# implement UI components like imageviews, recyclerviews inside google map <fragment> tag in android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, fragment

I'm implementing google maps and I want to change my xml code from

from

> ```
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/MapCenter"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_above="@id/rvMap"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>             android:src="@drawable/map_center" />
>
>         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>             android:id="@+id/rvMap"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_40sdp" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
> ```

to

> ```
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/MapCenter"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_above="@id/rvMap"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>             android:src="@drawable/map_center" />
>
>         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>             android:id="@+id/rvMap"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_40sdp" />
>     </fragment>
> ```

When I changed to fragment, It's not properly showing inside components, please let me know how to use Ui components inside fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout widget is not close, do this

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MapCenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/rvMap"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/map_center" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_40sdp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```